# How do I solve problem bootstrapping Tor Browser with raspberry

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My ISP don't block tor.So last weeks I have problem to connect tor browser. I have a raspberry pi that run tor. The below web page show my setup.

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-tor-access-point/

Then raspberry takes internet over wifi from router then connect over wifi to my laptop. I use this setup over 2 years and WORKS PERFECT, but 3 last weeks I have this error message when connect tor browser.

[WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (TLS_ERROR; TLS_ERROR; count 10; recommendation warn; host 42949C1EC1FEC5E30197E269FE7850CCA2FD0C0D at 51.75.54.88:443)

I tried to block above IP but the problem stills continue with other ip. The very strange is that sometimes it works with the above ip, and sometimes show the above problem the same ip. This problem stills with other ip.

I think the problem is Common log error #3: Failed to complete TLS handshake from this page:

https://support.torproject.org/connecting/connecting-2/

but if I open via ssh terminal from my linux machine to raspberry and I run sudo -u debian-tor nyx and inside nyx press one or two times "n" change identify then tor-browser works.

When I connect from my linux OS directly from my REAL IP (without I use rasbperry pi) to tor browser , everything is perfect. I don't use firewall.

Thank you very much.....

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> Re-entry into the network is now denied at the Exit level to all relays' ORPorts and authorities' ORPorts and DirPorts. This change should help mitgate a set of denial-of-service attacks. Closes ticket [2667](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/2667).

New "feature" in tor disallows Tor over Tor. Whether the "feature" works depends on if the specific exit operator you are using has updated to a new version of tor. Therefore you may see it work sometimes, while not other times.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So is there no solution? What can I do for that? I use this setup over 2 years, I didn't have any problem. Do you suggest me any solution except to put bridges in Tor-browser.

Comment: @user14770539 You need to make sure Tor Browser is allowed to circumvent the rpi's tor, or make it use your rpi's tor. IDK how to do either.

Comment: Tor browser allowed from raspberry. This setup works perfect long time ago. What do you mean with IDK? What is IDK? Pleas help me if you want! Thank you!

Comment: IDK: I Don't Know. I don't know how to do either of what I described above. But you need to allow Tor Browser to not connect through your raspberry pi's Tor or make Tor Browser use your raspberry pi's Tor.

Comment: As I said this setup is working over 2 years. Three weeks ago I have this problem. In my question describe how it works raspberry with tor. Do you want to show you torrc file settings in raspberry?